# Bind Dropdownlist using List collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a country list containing the Danish name and English name of the country.I need to Bind the English name from the list to a dropdownlist.

I tried something like

```
ddlCountry.Items.Clear();
ddlCountry.Items.Add(new ListItem("choose", ""));
var list = Country.GetCountryList();
ddlCountry.DataSource = list;
ddlCountry.DataBind();
```

But the dropdown only showing sting  "Country".I need to show the name of the country.
My list is like below picture [image]

Can any one help?

Comment: `ddlCountry.DataTextField = "EnglishName";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
var list = Country.GetCountryList().Select(x=>x.EnglishName);
```

This way using LINQ, you are selecting only the english name of the counrties that method called `GetCountryList()` returns.

Comment: @Arun you welcome dude. I am glad that I could help.